# virsh error: domain is already quiesced

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, snapshot, virsh, quiesce

My VM backup script fails while creating the snapshot.

```
virsh snapshot-create-as --domain machine_1 snap --diskspec vda,file=/srv/test/test-snap.qcow2 --disk-only --atomic --no-metadata --quiesce
error: Requested operation is not valid: domain is already quiesced
```

Even after a VM reboot, the system is still quiesced and I get the same error.

I thought quiesce means FS freeze, but this makes no sense since I can still write to the FS when logged in the faulty VMs. And this would not survive a reboot, right?

Could it be a communication issue that makes the host think the GA says the machine is quiesced while it is not?

In any case, is there a command to enquire the quiesce state (apart from attempting a snapshot and see if I get an error)?

Assuming the faulty VMs went quiesced after a unreproducible error, I could fix that by exiting quiesced state, whatever that means. Is there a virsh command to unquiesce the VM?

The whole backup procedure used to work and now it fails on 2 VMs but still works on 2 others and I can't think of any relevant difference between them.

Software versions:

- Host is Debian Jessie with qemu-kvm 2.8+dfsg-3~bop8+1 from backports.
- Guests are Debian Stretch with qemu-guest-agent 2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4.

(For the record, the backup script is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Nobatek/vmbackup/blob/master/vmbackup). Basically, what it does is 1/ create snapshot, 2/ copy, 3/ commit snapshot.)

If I remove the `quiesce` option from the snapshot command line, things work smooth. But obviously, this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1160084) that was fixed in libvirt 1.2.11.

> Fixed upstream by:
>
> ```
> commit 6085d917d5c5839b7ed351e99fadbbb56f5178fe
> Author: Michal Privoznik <mprivozn@redhat.com>
> Date: Thu Nov 27 11:43:56 2014 +0100
>
> qemu: Don't track quiesced state of FSs
>
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1160084
>
> As of b6d4dad11b (1.2.5) we are trying to keep the status of FSFreeze
> in the guest. Even though I've tried to fixed couple of corner cases
> (6ea54769ba18), it occurred to me just recently, that the approach is
> broken by design. Firstly, there are many other ways to talk to
> qemu-ga (even through libvirt) that filesystems can be thawed (e.g.
> qemu-agent-command) without libvirt noticing. Moreover, there are
> plenty of ways to thaw filesystems without even qemu-ga noticing (yes,
> qemu-ga keeps internal track of FSFreeze status). So, instead of
> keeping the track ourselves, or asking qemu-ga for stale state, it's
> the best to let qemu-ga deal with that (and possibly let guest kernel
> propagate an error).
>
> Moreover, there's one bug with the following approach, if fsfreeze
> command failed, we've executed fsthaw subsequently. So issuing
> domfsfreeze in virsh gave the following result:
>
> virsh # domfsfreeze gentoo
> Froze 1 filesystem(s)
>
> virsh # domfsfreeze gentoo
> error: Unable to freeze filesystems
> error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU agent command 'guest-fsfreeze-freeze': The command guest-fsfreeze-freeze has been disabled for this instance
>
> virsh # domfsfreeze gentoo
> Froze 1 filesystem(s)
>
> virsh # domfsfreeze gentoo
> error: Unable to freeze filesystems
> error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU agent command 'guest-fsfreeze-freeze': The command guest-fsfreeze-freeze has been disabled for this instance
> ```

Upgrading to a newer version fixes this.